# Permissions Error Creating New Folder on a Windows Share from Mac OSX

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx

I have a user who has a MacBook Pro. He connects to a Windows share and is able to browse through directories, open/edit/create documents, etc... He has FULL permissions on these directories and can do everything EXCEPT create a new folder. If he goes to menu and then Create New Folder, he gets an error saying he doesn't have permissions. Now, if he creates a new folder on his desktop and then drags it into the share, it works. Or, if I put his account into the Domain Admins group, the error will disappear also.

Is there an official solution to this problem without having to do one of the two workarounds that I listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain how he connects to the share? Do you use the Go>Connect to server menu option, and enter the share path as smb://server/share? If you connect this way and get him to authenticate using his domain credentials this should work. I think you still need to do this even if you've bound his Mac to the domain and get him to log in using his domain credentials.

Comment: He does just what you said; he selects GO-CONNECT TO A SERVER. Then enters SMB://servername/SHARED. He then enters his Windows domain account credentials when prompted.

His Mac is also joined to the domain.

Comment: How have you set the permissions? I.e. what are the share permissions and what are the security permissions?